# How to clear the file data from a multipart jsp

Tags: forms, jsp, servlets, caching, multipartform-data

I have a JSP form with form property (In order to submit multiple files) as 
 enctype = "multipart/form-data";
 encoding = "multipart/form-data";

When the form get submitted I'm reading the form data as

```
DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
ServletFileUpload fileUpload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
List<FileItem> fileItemList = fileUpload.parseRequest(request);
```

Now the issue I'm facing is that after the servlet process the request I'm coming back to the same page, after which if the user refreshes the page than based on the previous action performed the form is getting submitted again to the same servlet and I'm again getting the file which has been previously browsed and it's saving again.

Is there is any way we can clear the file information which has been browsed ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML code would have helped here. However, here is a solution that I think could help you resolve the issue.

You can reset the files associated with the file upload control by using

```
document.getElementById('yourFileInputControlId').files = '';
```

This should be done in java script immediately after your file upload request has been handled.(I am considering you are uploading your file using ajax)

If you are actually submitting the entire form rather than using Ajax, I do not see a reason why the file control would not reset. Please provide more details by editing the question if you still face the issue